# WordPress - как через SQL-запрос массово добавить в конец всех заголовков записей знак вопроса (?)?

Tags: sql, wordpress

WordPress - как через SQL-запрос массово добавить в конец всех заголовков записей знак вопроса (?) ?
Не нашёл таких подсказок через гугл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается простым запросом UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_title = concat(post_title, '?') WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
```

Comment: KAGG Design, благодарю! Отличное решение!